# I get an error when importing iAd

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

[image]

When I add this to my project:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> 
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface info : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UITabBarDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,UISplitViewControllerDelegate,ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

I get an error:

```
Could not build module "iAd"
```

When I create a new project, I can to this without issues!

Whats wrong in my project?

Comment: did you add the iAd framework to your project ? which Xcode version are you using ?

Comment: Hy... the iAD.framework is added in my Project..

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `project navigator` (App name in blue at the left pane of xcode), then `Build Phases`, then open `Link Binary With Libraries` and add iAd.framework in your project.